# Email Attachment Download Complete in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, email-attachments

I am working on a project in MEAN stack where I have to download the attachment to an email address and save it to DB.
For this, I am using [download-email-attachments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-email-attachments) which is successfully downloading the emails for a specified time. 
Now the problem is I need to run another code to save the files after all files are downloaded, but I couldn't get any endpoint for files downloaded in download-email-attachments. I tried to add a onEnd function, which is running before the file download starts. Here is my code:

```
// Attachment Download
var onEnd = function (result) {
  if (result.error) {
    console.log(result.error)
    return
  }
  console.log("Result:")
  console.log(result);
  if (undefined == result.latestTime) {

  }
}
var downloadEmailAttachments = require('download-email-attachments');
downloadEmailAttachments({
  account: '"email@gmail.com":password@imap.gmail.com:993',
  directory: 'files/',
  filenameFilter: /.zip?$/,
  timeout: 2000,
  log: {warn: console.warn, debug: console.info, error: console.error, info: console.info },
  since: '2018-02-14',
  attachmentHandler: function (attachmentData, cbfun, errorCB) {
    console.log(attachmentData)
    cbfun()
  }
}, onEnd);
// Attachment Download End
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: At this time, your `onEnd` function isn't doing anything except log `result` to the console. What would you need to change in `onEnd` to save to a file? You could create your own function `saveEmails` and pass it to `downloadEmailAttachments` instead of `onEnd`.

Comment: the problem is the onEnd function is getting called before downloading and saving any files. So even if I create an new function to save process the files, it won't work because the files aren't down when the function is called.
I an not sure why that is happening.